# Angular8 - observable inside service, how to notify the subscribed component based on logical code condition?

Tags: angular

I have a service which exposes a function that returns Observable. 
In this service I have some logic which should trigger a next call on the Observable so that subscribed 
component should get the updated data.
During Observer constructor I can call next and everything works great, 
but how can I access this outside of the constructor?

During service init I do

```
private currentWheaterData$: Observable<any>;

this.currentWheaterData$ = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(/* data */);
}
```

Then in other methods of the same service I want to be able to execute something like

```
this.currentWheaterData$.observer.next(/* fresh data */);
```

There must be a way to emit a new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to create a shared service that holds state, and can be used by components then you should use a `BehaviorSubject()` so that components will always receive the most recent state.

```js
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
   private _weather$ = new BehaviorSubject<WeatherData>(null);

   public function set(data: WeatherData) {
      this._weather$.next(data);
   }

   public function select(): Observable<WeatherData> {
      return this._weather.asObservable();
   }
}
```

The above will emit a `null` until the weather data is set. You can alternatively prevent the observable from emitting `null` and force subscribers to wait until the first data is availible by switching to a `new ReplaySubject<WeatherData>(1)` instead.

Services can grow in complexity and there are several third-party libraries that can handle state management. Two very popular ones are [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) and [NgXs](https://www.ngxs.io/), but if you're doing something small and want to stay simple. Try my tiny state service that can be used with any front-end framework.

https://github.com/reactgular/stateful

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `Subject`.

```
this.currentWeatherData$ = new Subject();
```

And then you can call at any point:

```
this.currentWeatherData$.next(/* data */);
```

in your component you subscribe same as observable:

```
this.currentWeatherData$.subscribe(/* data */)
```

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Comment: New subscribers will not get any weather data until a new event is emitted. You also misspelled weather.

Answer (score 2):

In your Weather Service:

```
public currentWheaterData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

Insert data into Subject - Source Component

```
constructor(private weatherService:WeatherService){}
this.weatherService.currentWheaterData.next('data');
```

Destination Component

```
subscription:Subscription

this.subscription = this.weatherService.currentWheaterData.asObservable().subscribe((data)=>{
console.log(data);
});
```

Also, unsubscribe when the component destroy

```
onDestroy(){
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```